# Powershell write-host not working when logged in as another admin

Tags: powershell, active-directory, windows-server-2008

I have the below powershell script that I call via a command prompt outputting any text to >> .log file. What it does is it creates 2 OU's based on variables from an input file, checks to see if those OU's got created and finally outputs to a .log file (this is entered in the command prompt). It works as expected when executing the code as a domain admin on the abc.acme.ldt.com domain; it creares the OU's and outputs the text to .log file as expected.

But I'm experiencing a weird problem when running it as a forest admin acme.ldt.com user (with local domain admin privileges on that child domain ABC); It's able to create the OU's successfully but for whatever the reason it does not output the text file to the .log file. If I check with a [ADSI]::Exists("full-manual-path") I get a TRUE in response, so the script does create the OU's but I just cant get the text to appear in the .log file as I do when executing as a domain admin on the ABC domain.

```
Import-Csv ".\source\input.csv" | ForEach {

If ($_.FQDN -eq $(gwmi win32_computersystem).domain) { $OU_Name1 = $_.'OU Name1' }
If ($_.FQDN -eq $(gwmi win32_computersystem).domain) { $OU_Name2 = $_.'OU Name2' }
If ($_.FQDN -eq $(gwmi win32_computersystem).domain) { $OU_Name3 = $_.'OU Name3' }
If ($_.FQDN -eq $(gwmi win32_computersystem).domain) { $Path1 = $_.'OU Path1' }
If ($_.FQDN -eq $(gwmi win32_computersystem).domain) { $Path2 = $_.'OU Path2' }
If ($_.FQDN -eq $(gwmi win32_computersystem).domain) { $Full_windows7_OU_Path2 = $_.'Full Windows 7 OU path2' }
```

}

```
New-ADorganizationalUnit -Name $OU_Name1 -Path "$Path1"
Start-Sleep -s 10
New-ADorganizationalUnit -Name $OU_Name2 -Path "$Path2"
New-ADorganizationalUnit -Name $OU_Name3 -Path "$Path2"

if ([ADSI]::Exists("LDAP://$Full_windows7_OU_Path2"))
{
Write-Host "# Checking Logs to Confirm the OU Structure For Win7 Has been created #"
} Else {
Exit
}
```

Comment: Seems like a permission issue on the share you want to write to. Are you absolutely positive that the user you use has write permissions on that share? If you login with that account and just try to write something to that location with `"test" | Out-File $location` does that work?

Comment: Wow the simplest detail, how did I ever overlook that!? So the forest admin did not have access to write to the .log file, giving it manual permission fixes the problem.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes the simplest things let us doubt ourselves..

As I said in the comment:

1. Check if that user has write permissions on the share with: `"test" | Out-File $location`

You're welcome :)